# How to trigger checked/unchecked events or Command of Checkbox in UWP using MVVM

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am new to UWP technology as well as new in MVVM too. I have multiple checkboxes on my page. See below:

[image]

A list of the checkboxes is inside the ListView and the ListView is inside the usercontrol. Data binding is done.

```
             <ListView
                    x:Name="listMenu"
                    MinHeight="60"
                    FontSize="14"
                    Foreground="White"
                    IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                    ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items, Mode=TwoWay}">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ListViewItem
                                Margin="0"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                Style="{StaticResource SettingsChangeLanguageListStyle}">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                    <CheckBox
                                        x:Name="termsOfServiceCheckBox"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                        Command="{Binding AreaOfExpertiseCommand}"
                                        Content="{Binding TopicName}"
                                        FontFamily="{StaticResource osRegular}"
                                        FontSize="14"
                                        Foreground="#636E7F"
                                        IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                        Style="{StaticResource CheckBoxCustomStyle}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </ListViewItem>
                        </DataTemplate>

                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>

                </ListView>
```

Now I want to trigger Checked/Uncheck event or Command to get my current checked or unchecked CheckBox using the MVVM pattern.

I have created a Dependency Property for Command which is not executing on checking/unchecking the checkbox.

```
 public ICommand AreaOfExpertiseCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(AreaOfExpertiseCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AreaOfExpertiseCommandProperty, value); }
    }

 public static readonly DependencyProperty AreaOfExpertiseCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(AreaOfExpertiseCommand), typeof(ICommand), typeof(AreaOfExpertiseUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

ViewModel.cs :

```
 public ICommand AreaOfExpertiseCommand => new RelayCommand(UpdateAreaOfExpertiseAsync);

 private void UpdateAreaOfExpertiseAsync()
 {

 }
```

Any help will be appreciated..

Comment: Are you running code as soon as a check box is checked? Would parameter passing to an ICommand property in the ViewModel suffice?

Comment: Do you mean the UpdateAreaOfExpertiseAsync method was not triggered when you checked or unchecked the checkBox? When I tested your code snippet, the UpdateAreaOfExpertiseAsync  method can be triggered successfully, can you provide a simple sample that can be reproduced for us to test? In addition, I'm confused why you created a Dependency Property for Command? You didn't use it from your code snippet, you just need to create the command property in your viewmodel.

Comment: @ChrisBD I am binding IsChecked property of checkbox on page load. I am not passing any parameters.

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT Yes, UpdateAreaOfExpertiseAsync is not triggering when I checked or unchecked the checkbox. My Checkbox list is in separate user control that's why I created a Dependency Property, I called it from my view where i added this checkbox control. I may be wrong, I am completely new to these technologies.

Comment: The UpdateAreaOfExpertiseAsync method can be triggered when I tested, so can you provide a simple sample that can be reproduced for us to test?

Comment: Your ListView has a Source binding to what I assume is a collection called Items. Are you binding to ICommand implementations within those objects or to the ViewModel that holds the collection?

Comment: @ChrisBD you are right. Collection Items is set as a source and yes binding within those objects and not the whole ViewModel. Is anything wrong there in my code? Do you have any sample/article link which shows how the value of the checkbox will be updated in the database using MVVM pattern in UWP

Comment: @ShrikantDandile The code snippet you showed is not complete, it's hard to tell where is wrong, please provide complete repro sample.